# Why can't I get cookie value in Playwright?

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy, playwright

> Firstly, sry for my poor English

I want to use playwright to get the cookie, but I can't.
I tried 3 ways I've found, and got nothing.

1. Using `page.on`

```py
page.on('request',get_cookie)
page.on('response',get_cookie)

def get_cookie(request):
    allheaders = request.all_headers()
    print(allheaders)


>>>
{'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'age': '9576', 'cache-control': 'max-age=600', 'content-length': '6745', 'content-type': 'image/png', 'date': 'Thu, 30 Jun 2022 01:09:20 GMT', 'etag': '"206578bcab2ad71:0"', 'expires': 'Thu, 30 Jun 2022 01:19:20 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Tue, 06 Apr 2021 06:11:52 GMT', 'server': 'NWS_SPMid', 'x-cache-lookup': 'Cache Hit', 'x-daa-tunnel': 'hop_count=1', 'x-nws-log-uuid': '16892018456232999193', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET'}
{'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'age': '9576', 'cache-control': 'max-age=600', 'content-length': '6745', 'content-type': 'image/png', 'date': 'Thu, 30 Jun 2022 01:09:20 GMT', 'etag': '"206578bcab2ad71:0"', 'expires': 'Thu, 30 Jun 2022 01:19:20 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Tue, 06 Apr 2021 06:11:52 GMT', 'server': 'NWS_SPMid', 'x-cache-lookup': 'Cache Hit', 'x-daa-tunnel': 'hop_count=1', 'x-nws-log-uuid': '16892018456232999193', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET'}
...(and more like this)
```

returned somthing, but no cookie here

2. Using `browser_context.cookies` Resolved! Thx for @Charchit

```py
context = browser.new_context();
page = context.new_page()
page.goto(url)
cookies = context.cookies
print(cookies)

>>>
<bound method BrowserContext.cookies of <BrowserContext browser=<Browser type=<BrowserType name=chromium executable_path=/Users/swong/Library/Caches/ms-playwright/chromium-1005/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium> version=102.0.5005.40>>>
```

3. Using JS

```py
cookie = page.evaluate('console.log(document.cookie)')
print(cookie)

>>>
None
```

I opened the network tab from the Chromium page,there was the cookie I want in Requests' header.

please help me, Thank you all!

Here's my code example. The site is in Chinese language, and hope you will not mind it. It's just a simple login page.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

url = 'https://so.gushiwen.cn/user/login.aspx'

def get_cookie(request_or_reqponse):
    headersArray = request_or_reqponse.headers_array()
    print('「headersArray」：', headersArray)


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context();
    page = context.new_page()

    page.goto(url)
    page.fill('#email','6j3y4ecy@spymail.one')
    page.fill('#pwd', '6j3y4ecy@spymail.one')

    page.wait_for_timeout(5000) # imput the captcha code manually

    page.on('request',get_cookie)
    page.on('response',get_cookie)

    print('loging in...')
    page.click('#denglu')

    page.wait_for_timeout(50000) # wait for nothing

    browser.close()
```

Comment: you could create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with URL so we could copy and test code.

Comment: Fixed it. Sry I'm new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second method, change `cookies = context.cookies` to `cookies = context.cookies()`. It's a method, you need to call it. Check the  [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-cookies):

```
context = browser.new_context();
page = context.new_page()
page.goto(url)
cookies = context.cookies()
print(cookies)
```

Also, doing it like your first method is not advisable. This is because even if you get the `Cookie` header from the response, you can't really store and use it else where unless you use a factory function or a global variable. Besides, why do that when `BrowserContext` specifically has a method for it :)

**Edit**

The reason the first method seemingly does not work is because it returns the headers of the request and responses made. Cookies can also be created through javascript on the page itself, these may not show up in the headers at all.

Secondly, from the headers you have printed out for the first method in your question, it seems like it was only for a single request. After running your code, there were a lot more requests and responses received, which in place printed out a lot more headers. From the responses in particular, you can retrieve the cookies set by the server by searching for the header `'set-cookie'`.

Comment: Thx! I got it. But has a little difference with the cookie from console.
Any way, this cookie worked, thx again.

and...Although the first method is not advisable, I still curious why it can't get the right cookie :(

Comment: @SSjoewvv check my edit

Comment: Aye yes, I got a lot of requests and responses by using `page.on` too. I want the page be clear ,so just post one return. Sry about that make some misunderstanding

And thanks a lot for your Edit content.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com')
cookies = page.context.cookies()
print(cookies)
```